# How to give path of xls file residing in assets folder of android project using Apache POI

Tags: android, apache-poi, android-file, android-assets

I want to read .xls file residing in assets folder of android project. I'm using apache POI to read the file.

But I'm not sure what could be the path of the file residing in assets folder.

My code is as below:

```
// Creating Input Stream 
File file = new File("file:///assets/test.xls");
FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);

// Create a POIFSFileSystem object 
POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

// Create a workbook using the File System 
HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

// Get the first sheet from workbook 
HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Using this code, I get following error:

```
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/assets/test.xls: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417):     at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17273)
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 11:10:36.531: W/System.err(4417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
07-08 11:10:36.539: W/System.err(4417):     ... 13 more
```

What path do I have to provide to read my xls file??

Answer (score 1):

```
file:///assets/test.xls
```

This above syntax is incorrect.

The path must  be separated by two slashes, like this:

```
C:\\\Users\\\user\\\Desktop\\\something.xls.
```

Comment: so what according to you should be the path of my file? should it be "file:\\assets\\test.xls"?? I tried this but it is not working. I get the same error.

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to do a "File:\\" path instead of a directory path?

Comment: how would I find C directory from phone!!? I want to keep it with my apk so that I can read it when I need it. Is there any other way to do so?